# Moving mesh in pose mode is deforming inappropriately

Tags: rigging, armature

My first character rig. I have pauldrons that are supposed to be in line with when the upper arm moves but when the upper arm moves, they deform horribly.

[image: upper arm moving]

As you see it becomes smaller...

but when I move the clavicle, the pauldron moves just fine and doesn't deform
[image: clavicle moving]

How do I get this movement on the upper arm without it deforming, like the clavicle's movement?

[.blend file](http://dropbox.com/s/ikqenlyl9bfuipk/person.blend?dl=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clavicle bone will by default also move the arm as the arm is its child. Therefore the pauldron should only be weighted to the arm and not the the clavicle. Due to the way armature deformation is calculated, volume loss like this can occur when solving between a number of weights (checking preserve volume on the armature modifier can help, but it can cause other artifacts as well.

Another thing you may want to do is make a separate bone to control the pauldron and use contraints to mix rotation from the clavicle and arm onto the new bone.

(At work so I can't check the blend file, you may also want to check to see if any other bones have influence on the pauldron)

Comment: Thank you! After painting it to the upper arm, it was still moving weirdly, so I ended up taking the second advice and making a separate bone for the pauldron that is a child of the upper arm.